# Toggling between filtered GraphQL query results using Apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

In my schema, I have a type (ContentBlock) that contains an array of nested entities (Variations) using the Relay standard connection (edges, node, etc.). I've got a view that allows the user to specify some filter criteria, which then gets passes as an argument to the ContentBlock type, and returns a filtered set of Variations (the filtering is complex and must be done on the server). I've also got a view with a different query that passes no argument to ContentBlock, and so gets back ALL of the nested Variations.

When toggling from the "show all" view to the "filtered" view, Apollo performs the filtered query, and the store gets updated such that each ContentBlock entity's list of Variations now only contains the filtered result. But, if I now return to the "show all" view, I still only have the filtered result.

I know I could always do a `.refetch()` on the "show all" query when I hit that view, but I'm wondering if anyone has a suggestion of a way I could change my schema, query, or store so that I can maintain both the filtered result alongside the full result and not have to go back to the server for data when toggling between views.

Even as I write this, I'm contemplating adding a field to the schema that contains the filtered list of Variation ids - that way I could still return all Variations but only show the filtered ones? But, there are other cases in my app where I really *don't* need to fetch all of them (the "show all" is an admin view, most users will only ever get the filtered set).

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the structure of your application. As far as I know Apollo Client will store each list in a different place if any of the arguments to the list field are different, so you should have both available

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at what happens in the store using the Apollo Client devtools. That might help.